# python search module path script with arguments not working

Tags: python

To find a module's path, I would like to use the following script:

```
import <module_name>
print <module_name>.__file__
```

It works.

However, I want to make it more flexible, to receive an argument to specify the module's name.

If I name the script as searchModulePath.py, I want to run it with `searchModulePath.py <some_module_name>`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#!usr/bin/python

import sys
print sys.argv
import sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[1].__file__
```

But it doesn't work:

```
  File "searchModulePath.py", line 5
    import sys.argv[1]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And, the print statement in the 2nd line doesn't print out anything, :(

Anything I missed here?

Comment: You can't use variables in import statements, you need to use the builtin `__import__` in stead:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables in import statements, you should use the builtin [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) in stead:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
module = __import__(sys.argv[1])
print module.__file__
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you say

```
module = __import__(sys.argv[1])
print(module.__file__)
```

(Assuming the module is implemented as a file; `sys` and `__builtins__` are not.)